# updating an entity's property without retrieving the entity from the NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I would like to update a property of an entity that has a lot of properties.

If I understand it correctly, whenever I retrieve the entity from the datastore by

```
entity = key_of_entity.get()
```

to later update it's property

```
entity.some_property += 1
entity.put()
```

I am charged for read of every property of that entity? Since this entity has quite a few properties, such reading over and over again can be quite expensive. Is there any way to update an entity's property without having to do a read on it first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solution is to split this entity into two parts: rarely updated and frequently updated. You can make them totally independent (with an id of one entity as a property in another entity), or you can make one of them a parent and the other one a child.

Comment: @dreamwalker as well you can have the same key for 2 different entities, using one to read data, and another to write or what fits you most.

Comment: Yes sorry for that Andrei. I use this approach most of the times when I have control over the id and do not need an auto-generated one.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is part of the confusion, but my understanding is that @Jimmy's idea is to have the same key name but two different kinds (so the keys are still unique).

Comment: @PatrickCostello yes... correct. The confusion comes with ndb's key_name etc. We all three are saying the same.