# Splitting entities vs. using transactions

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity with two types of properties:

1. Properties that are updated by the user from a web page.
2. Properties that are updated when a third-party service makes an API call to my app.

If my entity only had properties of the first type, I wouldn't use transactions to do updates because only a single user would ever be modifying the data.

Because a third-party service will be making calls that will also by updating the entity, there is now a risk of losing data if the user is making an edit at the same time as the API call.

It seems that to avoid data loss, I could do one of two things:

1. Use transactions for all puts of this entity (they happen in a lot of different places so it would be a fair bit of work), or
2. Split the entity in two where a first entity has properties of the first type that are updated without transactions and a second entity that has properties of the second type (that may be updated with transactions).

I'm having trouble deciding which is the better option, and would appreciate advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with entities split avoiding transactions for the web-interface modified entities *might* not be as clear/easy as you *might* expect:

- the user may attempt to modify the same entity from different sessions/windows/devices
- the info displayed to the user right after it was modified *might* not be the one actually existing in the datastore due to eventual consistency

In other words it *might* be safer (and potentially easier, futureproof) to have transactions on the user web interface as well.

But even if do that, it might still make sense to split the entitites if it makes sense for your app, it's a common technique, see:

- [updating an entity's property without retrieving the entity from the NDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103245/updating-an-entitys-property-without-retrieving-the-entity-from-the-ndb/22103434#22103434)
- [Google App Engine Datastore entities. Efficiency and structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582513/google-app-engine-datastore-entities-efficiency-and-structure/36583558#36583558)
- [re-using an entity's ID for other entities of different kinds - sane idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954102/re-using-an-entitys-id-for-other-entities-of-different-kinds-sane-idea)

Comment: Thanks, the linked posts about frequently-changed vs. rarely changed properties are very helpful.  Regarding the first part of your answer, do you almost always update entities with transactions?

Comment: I started thinking like you, only to run into problems and adding more and more transactions. Very few non-transactional updates left, and I'm not quite sure I'm done with them yet :) None left in the GUI area.